# Should I check the “Use scalar properties for primitive data types” when generating a new NSManagedObject subclass from my model file?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I created a project using Core Data, and in the .model file I created an entity called Targets.

I added these two entity attributes:

```
content (String)
targetID (Integer 32)
```

When I generate the NSManagedObject subclass Xcode asks me:

> Use scalar properties for primitive data types?

Should I check this box when generating a new NSManagedObject subclass from my model file?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If the box is checked, Xcode will generate scalar types (e.g., int, float, double) for those attributes. If not checked, the attributes will be `NSNumber`s.

Answer (score 4):

If checking the option, the default value for `Number` type what you get will be zero, but `nil` is more reasonable. So, I don't think you should check the box.